# Why Django Rest Framework SessionAuthentication doesn't require csrf for unauthenticated users?

Tags: python, django, rest, session, django-rest-framework

I've found this in Django Rest Framework docs:

> CSRF validation in REST framework works slightly differently to standard Django due to the need to support both session and non-session based authentication to the same views. This means that only authenticated requests require CSRF tokens, and anonymous requests may be sent without CSRF tokens

By default DRF uses those authentication classes:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES'= (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
),
```

What would be the problem in supporting both session and non-session based authentication while checking csrf token for unauthenticated users (using SessionAuthentication class)?